# What did I do yesterday Rebus?

Tags: mathematics, rebus

[image]

What did I do yesterday ? Above image is the rebus.

Src : slightly copied .

Comment: LOL at the belly button!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe it means:

> $$ \sqrt{\frac{-1}{64}} = \frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{64}} = \frac{\sqrt{-1}}{8} = \frac{i}{8} = i~~over~~ate$$
>  You could see that the 8 on 2018 resembles myself who eats a lot...

Comment: I'd even suggest "I overate before 2018"

Comment: @TeunD or "at the start of," considering yesterday was the beginning of 2018.